# Strange behaviour of python libraries

Tags: python, pip

Sorry for the ambiguous title but I am not sure how I can describe the issue in a few words.

I have two containers, A and B. Both containers have the following python package:

```
python-keystoneclient (3.5.0)
```

I have the following simple code:

```
import keystoneclient.openstack.common.apiclient

print "hello"
```

When executing it, container A outputs "hello" whereas container B outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keystoneclient.openstack.common.apiclient
ImportError: No module named openstack.common.apiclient
```

I downloaded the source code of the python package (python-keystoneclient 3.5) and that library is not there anymore. It was removed long ago. Therefore, I am confused and I cannot understand why container A does not throw any error and it is capable of importing the library.

Comment: Were the same packages installed in the containers in the same way?

Comment: No. The one where things work is several weeks older. Could it be that I was using it while python-keystoneclient had that library and it saved it in memory somehow? Could it be that the library comes from another packet?

Comment: Do you have a Python file or a folder called `keystoneclient` in your project folder?

Comment: @M.Buil I dont know but it from the sounds of things there is a difference between the two packages. Have you checked the contents of each?

Comment: @Klaus D. You might be close to the solution. I searched for keystoneclient and I got two paths:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient &&
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient

Both paths have a subdirectory openstack/common/apiclient in the container where things work. However, the container where things do not work, is missing that subdirectory in the /usr/local/lib... path.